# Is it possible to use a ttf font with print/preview font in IE 10 and IE 9?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, font-face

I have a font for which I cannot modify the permissions to be Installable, as required by IE. I also tried the fontsquirrel hack by converting font to eot and woff, but only IE 9 downloads the eot font, not IE11,10,8.

So is it possible to use the .ttf file with preview/print permissions only. I am not allowed to change the permissions to be installable.

Comment: Do the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20425523/custom-fonts-not-displaying-within-ie9-ie10) help? (If so, this is probably a duplicate.)

Comment: Hi @MrLister , I have checked that question. In IE9, the eot file is getting downloaded, not in other versions of IE.